# Apache2 Virtual Host broken; displayed default index.html on subdomain, but correct content on www.subdomain

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I've got a Linode configured as a Ubuntu 10.04.2 web server with Apache 2.2.14.

I have a total of 4 sites, all defined under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` as virtual hosts. All sites are almost identical clones for configuration. And all sites but my last work successfully.

```
default:      (www.)exampleadnetwork.com
              (www.)example.com
          reseller.example.com
trouble:   client1.example.com
```

I keep getting this page when I visit the `client1.example.com` site:

> ### It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

In my `ports.conf` file I have the NameVirtualHost correctly set to my IP address on port 80.

If I access the "www.sub.example.com" alias the site works! If I access it without the www I see the "It Works" excerpt posted above. Even `apache2ctl -S` shows that my vhost file parses correctly and is added to the mix.

My vhost configuration file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  client1.example.com
    ServerAlias client1.example.com www.client1.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/www/client1.example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog    /srv/www/client1.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog   /srv/www/client1.example.com/logs/access.log combined

    <directory /srv/www/client1.example.com/public_html/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The other sites are variations of:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias example.com www.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog    /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog   /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The only site the differs is the other subdomain:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  reseller.example.com
    ServerAlias reseller.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/www/reseller.example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog    /srv/www/reseller.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog   /srv/www/reseller.example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Filenames are the FQDN without the www. prefix.

I've followed [this advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/146673/why-cant-i-get-rid-of-default-index-html-even-if-i-disable-the-default-virtual-h), but still cannot access subdomain properly.

Comment: Your config only shows us one of the 3 sites where are the other's configured and how?

Comment: They're also configured under /etc/apache2/sites-available in nearly identical ways. The only thing that changes for each of these is the server name to the domain name(s) it handles, and the physical path.

Comment: The contents of the files and the filenames are important.

Comment: Is there anything relevant in your error and access logs ?

Comment: @Iain, no nothing. The apache error log shows nothing, and the access logs for the vhosted site only list access to the www.client1.[...] site (no errors for the one without the www.).

Comment: I would be obliged if someone would place a bounty on this (I would, but I don't have the reputation), my deadline is Wednesday.

Comment: You mention sites-available, but that directory doesn't really matter much, what is listed in sites-enabled?  Did you run `a2ensite` to create the symlink from enabled -> available?

Comment: @The Wicked Flea, your question hasn't existed long enough for there to be a bounty.

Comment: All sites that I listed are enabled as well. I meant that their files are in sites-available.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same problem and eventually what solved the problem was when I disabled the default site in apache by unlinking it from sites-enabled:

```
sudo unlink /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

After doing this, all my sites displayed correctly. I see this question is quite old, but hope this can help someone else out there.

Comment: I did this, to no success.

Comment: I used a2dissite and reloaded apache - and it worked. It was only on my main virtual host it was doing this... My guess was that the 000-default was the first virtual host to match so it never read the one I wanted it to use.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of the other posters will do it.

You "it Works" is shown, becase all your Virtuall Host match to localhost.
And if you call "client1.example.com" apache will skipp the localhost Vhosts and if there is no matching Vhost, it will use se default config.

Do what the other posters told (change your vitial hosts to `<VirtualHost *:80>` of `<VirtualHost *>` of change your default vhost to the Document root you like.

**Don`t forget:** even if you define your Vhosts correctly, the server will call the default site if some one requests your server without a hostname (e.g. via ip address).

Answer (score 0):

Try it without having a duplicate entry in ServerName and ServerAlias.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
ServerName  sub.example.com
ServerAlias www.sub.example.com
DocumentRoot    /srv/www/sub.example.com/public_html/
ErrorLog    /srv/www/sub.example.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog   /srv/www/sub.example.com/logs/access.log combined

<directory /srv/www/sub.example.com/public_html/>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</directory>
```

Comment: Tried that. I can still access both addresses, but only the one with the www. prefix operates correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Change the `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>` for `<VirtualHost *:80>`
- Did you place the `NameVirtualHost *:80` configuration?
- Place an index.html file under each DocumentRoot, obviously each with a different message to identify where are you accessing
- Try accessing from localhost and if it's possible try from another location

Comment: In FILO order: Localhost access is identical to remote; no need for an index file, all are distinct (but the one gives a "It works" page instead of an Install Wordpress page; transitioning to *:80 from the IP address produces the same result.

Comment: Did you place "NameVirtualHost *:80"?

Comment: Yes. It was already there, I just changed the IP to a *.

Comment: I just copied your configuration in my desktop and it works fine. There must be something else, some other config or maybe a browser problem? Cache or something?

Comment: Tried with FF, Chrome, and cURL w/the same result. Must be something else in my config files that is doing it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the vhosts in the conf file? Does it change anything?

Comment: The vhosts are all separate files under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` named by their FQDN without the www prefix. I said this in my post.

Comment: @RobertK “Localhost access is identical to remote; no need for an index file” you do realize that the whole concept of `NameVirtualHost` is based on remote access so the hostname is conveyed to Apache & the Apache routes the traffic based on `NameVirtualHost` settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the DNS resolution of your sites?

(www.)sub.example.com both resolves to the same machine (even if different addresses)?

Check the logs, both of them, to see if all your access are hitting the proper server (configuration), or if they are hitting the default, since the "It Works!" is the default page, of the default configuration.

If they are hitting the default, you have to identify why is that so... what are the differences between the configurations.  Try changing the IP, as suggested before, since Apache will bind the configuration to the specific IP address stated on the VirtualHost directive.

Answer (score 0):

Your configs are not setup properly for `NameVirualHost`. Get rid of the the `127.0.0.1` and make that a wildcard of `*`. When you explicitly set `127.0.0.1` that will bind all connections on your machine to that config. `NameVirualHost` needs a wildcard of `*`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  client1.example.com
    ServerAlias client1.example.com www.client1.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/www/client1.example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog    /srv/www/client1.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog   /srv/www/client1.example.com/logs/access.log combined

    <directory /srv/www/client1.example.com/public_html/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
The other sites are variations of:

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias example.com www.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog    /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog   /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
The only site the differs is the other subdomain:

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName  reseller.example.com
    ServerAlias reseller.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /srv/www/reseller.example.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog    /srv/www/reseller.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog   /srv/www/reseller.example.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, make sure that `NameVirtualHost` is set as follows. On my setup under Ubuntu you will see that line in this file: `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```